# Return third-party response objects - com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException

Tags: java, swagger, spring-restcontroller, jackson-databind

I am building a POC project that consumes a third-party SDK. The SDK has a response object and for the sake of exploratory testing I need to return the same response in the controller. Returning the response directly throws an exception `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class`

So I wrap this response to string by:

```
    ThirdPartyResponseObject res = myService.getSomething();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure( SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
    String someJsonString = null;
    try {
        someJsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(res);
    } catch ( JsonProcessingException e ) {

    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>( someJsonString, HttpStatus.OK );
```

This returns the response as a string(eg. `{"context":{"errors":[],"errorCount":0,"level":0...`) which is fine but is not friendly to view the response in Swagger since the string is just too long and not able to see the hierarchy of json elements.

So I tried to parse this json string to a `JsonElement` and return the json element by:

```
ThirdPartyResponseObject res = myService.getSomething();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure( SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
String someJsonString = null;
JsonElement jsonElement = null;
try {
    someJsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(res);
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    jsonElement = parser.parse( someJsonString );       
} catch ( JsonProcessingException e ) {

}
return new ResponseEntity<>( jsonElement, HttpStatus.OK );
```

But this throws an exception `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: JsonObject`

I need to return the response so that it is formatted as json. Something like:

```
{
    "context":
    {
        "errors":[],
        "errorCount":0,
        "level":0
        ...
    }
}
```

Updated to add error details below:

```
Could not write JSON: JsonObject; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: JsonObject (through reference chain: com.google.gson.JsonObject["asString"])
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: JsonObject; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: JsonObject (through reference chain: com.google.gson.JsonObject["asString"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:293) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:106) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:231) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:203) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace. It will be helpful in understanding the underlying problem.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `JsonNode` works for me. Code will look like this:

```
    ThirdParyResponseObject res = myService.getSomething();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure( SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
    String someJsonString = null;
    JsonNode node = null;
    try {
        someJsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(res);
        node = mapper.readTree(someJsonString);
        return new ResponseEntity<>( node, HttpStatus.OK );
    } catch ( JsonProcessingException e ) {
        //log.error( e );
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        //log.error( e );
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>( node, HttpStatus.OK );
```